# Prove that $T(\mathbb Q)$ is metrizable while $T(\mathbb P)$ is not.

Tags: general-topology

Let $d_E$ be Euclidean metric and $T_{d_E}$ thus a canonical Topology on $\mathbb R$.

Given a dense set $D \subset \underline{\mathbb R}$ we define a Basis as $\mathcal B(D) = T_{d_E} \cup P(D)$, where $P(D)$ is the power set of $D$.

We then proceed by constructing a topology $T(D)$ using the basis $\mathcal B(D)$ from the previous step thus producing a topological space $(\mathbb R, T(D))$.

How can we prove that $T(\mathbb Q)$ is metrizable while $T(\mathbb P)$ is not? Here $\mathbb Q$ is the set of rationals and $\mathbb P$ is the set of irrationals.

Comment: What's $T_{d_E}$?

Comment: Question Edited.

Comment: Nagata-Smirnov theorem provides a completely characterisation of metrisable topological spaces. The theorem says that the topology of $X$ is given by a metric $d$ if and only if $X$ is regular, Hausdorff and admits a countably locally finite base for its topology. I suggest you prove that $T(P)$ does not satisfy this last requirement. I think the cardinality of the prime numbers has something to do, but it might be trickier that what it seems at first sight.

Comment: On the other hand, $T_2$ and the existence of a countably locally finite base are granted for $T(Q)$ (since you're defining a base, only $D$, and not $P(D)$, is necessary) so the only think that must be checked is regularity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T(\Bbb Q)$ has a countable base; find it. It's also easy to see it's $T_3$ so that Urysohn applies.

$T(\Bbb P)$ is called the Michael line. See [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/michael-line-basics/) for more info. $\Bbb Q$ is closed but not a $G_\delta$ in it so the space is not metrisable.

Comment: I'm not sure $T(\mathbb P)$ that I describe above is the Michael-Line as the latter unites the canonical topology on $\mathbb R$ with the singletons in $\mathbb P$. The one I am describing is called D-Scattered Line and unites it with the **power-set** of $\mathbb P$. Or are these definitions equivalent? They seem to be but I'm not sure.

Comment: @СССР The Michael line *is* the same space: we have all usual open subsets of $\Bbb R$ that are still open and all subsets of $\Bbb P$ that are open too, and we have the smallest topology with those properties. Why your doubts?

Comment: Just the definitions are different and so I was not sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give it a try... just a concrete metric for the case $T(\mathbb{Q})$.

Take an enumeration of
$$\mathbb{Q} = \{q_1, q_2, \dotsc\}.$$
Identify $\mathbb{R}$ and a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$:
\begin{align*}\iota: \mathbb{R} &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \\ x &\mapsto \begin{cases}(x,0), &x \not \in \mathbb{Q}\\(x,1/n),&x = q_n\end{cases}\end{align*}

I guess the image of $\iota$ is basically your $T(\mathbb{Q})$. It is metrizable as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.